# How should we get cumulative columns for different types of variables?

Tags: r, filtering, subset, cumulative-sum

my data is something like this:

```
structure(c("Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Material Efficiencie", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "28859", "15134", "29429", "14214", "37988", 
"15328", "42679", "46206", "43311", "8158", "29937", "6021", 
"5581", "44627", "36779", "15888", "20088", "42170", "11560", 
"16401", "30293", "27682", "44574", "20240", "10176", "45920", 
"40615", "28510", "23527", "35717", "12608", "30585", "1344", 
"30179", "38589", "18135", "32662", "577", "47836", "36944", 
"8946", "36730", "6499", "47177", "31564", "17612", "19799", 
"43469", "780", "29003", "729", "39209", "8237", "12442", "40877", 
"45338", "44977", "2081", "47886", "19948", "38960", "27127", 
"33186", "36972", "29774", "24197", "47513", "21171", "10992", 
"2630", "39740", "38639", "8373", "7932", "44641", "8877", "4256", 
"47425", "4972", "11793", "48437", "15102", "30181", "23058", 
"27086", "11750", "32797", "33320", "42980", "2712", "3360", 
"18773", "34625", "48207", "18044", "16727", "36327", "38051", 
"39081", "35858", "11747", "32221", "45342", "25444", "27538", 
"3725", "29636", "37667", "24387", "43088", "49972", "39308", 
"17497", "26198", "42199", "20640", "26455", "42792", "36511", 
"16867", "34142", "10629", "15415", "38989", "24381", "45988", 
"19603", "40886", "16616", "13004", "8370", "34725", "17915", 
"29838", "38500", "10620", "45602", "11911", "38119", "308", 
"37473", "17560", "14887", "30872", "7622", "20169", "38494", 
"12728", "14816", "37183", "18602", "157", "49615", "12902", 
"31344", "15606", "30386", "49746", "26466", "19784", "9326", 
"33639", "25323", "31404", "20045", "45788", "49454", "13271", 
"44675", "44926", "33041"), .Dim = c(171L, 2L))
```

Now what i want to do is get a separate cumulative sum table for different savings type. That is i want a separate cumulative sum table for NPI Efficiencie, for Manufacturing Excel, and for Material Efficiencies. is there anyways i can do this with the help of R. Please help!

Comment: You have a `matrix` of `character` class.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.frame(dt) %>% setDT
dt[, X2 := as.character(X2) %>% as.numeric]
dt[, cumsum_by_group := cumsum(X2), by = X1]
```